# Multiple file upload identification

Tags: php

I am using file upload input with `multiple` attribute. The output of my $_FILES is as follows:

```
 [kadFile] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Txt1.txt
                    [1] => Doc1.docx
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => text/plain
                    [1] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpE515.tmp
                    [1] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpE525.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 824
                    [1] => 768066
                )

        )
```

Is there a way to identify these files by giving them a specific name through javascript let's say or any other way so that they will be POST-ED as follows:

```
 [kadFile] => Array
            (
                [name] => Array
                    (
                        ["kadFile_txt1"] => Txt1.txt
                        ["kadFile_doc1"] => Doc1.docx
                    ) ...
```

I need to pass specific properties to each file by creating dynamic input fields when the files are selected, these fields have a naming convention, (the file input name + the selected file name + specific field identifier). At the server level I need to save each file and add these extra properties one shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an associative array if you want to as long as you preserve the the settings. Then treat `$new` in place of the `$_FILES` array, something like this:

```
foreach($_FILES['kadFile']['name'] as $key => $value) {
        // This is not the greatest of regex, but works for your example
        preg_match('/([^\.]+).([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})/',$value,$exp);
        $nKey   =   $exp[1];
        $new['kadFile']['name']["kadFile_".$nKey]       =   $value;
        $new['kadFile']['tmp_name']["kadFile_".$nKey]   =   $_FILES['kadFile']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $new['kadFile']['error']["kadFile_".$nKey]      =   $_FILES['kadFile']['error'][$key];
        $new['kadFile']['size']["kadFile_".$nKey]       =   $_FILES['kadFile']['size'][$key];

    }

echo print_r($new);
```

Comment: Seems reasonable enough, with some manipulations I can achieve what I want. I bet this is the only way. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, I do it all the time but I do the grouping like @Abijeet Patro's link. It's just more readable.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you cannot change the uploaded file names via JavaScript. Did you think of using separate file controls?

OR on the JavaScript, I guess you can add hidden fields on the **change** event of the file control.

I would create the hidden fields with the name as `hdn_"fileName"` and the value as whatever you want to keep.

Then when you start looping over the files in `$_FILES` you can access these hidden field values (based on the current file name) from the `$_POST` and do whatever you want.

Comment: Well I can do this currently with the index of the file, such as `kadFile_0_myField`, which is fine, but I was wondering if I can manipulate the keys to become associative rather than numeric in the `$_FILES` array

Comment: I'm not sure that you can - http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php#91479

Comment: Thanks dude for the help